# Retrieving images from Firebase Storage and display in recycler view

Tags: android

I've uploaded images to firebase storage and created two separated folders. The images are uploaded successfully but the problem is retrieving those images.

I've searched the internet and the tutorials I found everywhere were of **DatabaseReference** not StorageReference. I want to get those images and display in RecyclerView.

Code used to upload:

```
   StorageReference childRef = storageReference.child((String)spinner.getSelectedItem());


            //uploading the image
            UploadTask uploadTask = childRef.child(name).putFile(FilePathUri);

            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    etName.setText("");
                    selectedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_add_dark);
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Upload successful", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Upload failed", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

RecyclerView Adapter:

```
    public RCAdapter(Context context, List<DataModel> dataModels) {
    this.dataModels = dataModels;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    DataModel upload = dataModels.get(position);

    Glide.with(context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataModels.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ated two separated folders. The images are uploaded successfully but the problem is retrieving those images.

I've searched the internet and the tutorials I found everywhere were of DatabaseReference not StorageReference. I want to get those images and display in RecyclerView.

Code used to upload:

StorageReference childRef = storageReference.child((String)spinner.getSelectedItem());

```
        //uploading the image
        UploadTask uploadTask = childRef.child(name).putFile(FilePathUri);

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                etName.setText("");
                selectedImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_add_dark);
                Snackbar.make(view, "Upload successful", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Snackbar.make(view, "Upload failed", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```